# Transition from Firefox to Opera installing a decent Adblocker?

Tags: firefox, opera

I'm sick of Firefox and I want to move to Opera. It has anything I want to have but only the add-ons aren't so many and so good. Is there a decent Adblock plugin for Opera? Currently I'm using NoAds Advance but it's very restrictive and blocks many Javascripts. I need to manually deblock it. In Firefox I used Adblock plus and I only need to check for a list at the installation. In Opera I check a list, too, but the add-on still block many scripts. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [Opera AdBlock extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/opera-adblock/) and start with [Fanboy's list for Opera](http://www.fanboy.co.nz/adblock/opera/).

Answer (score 3):

You can Use the Extension [AdBlock](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/opera-adblock/), This Works Great, This Also Have Some Advance Option Available but are Hidden.